# modification need on aodv.cc file for routing packet between MANET and wired network

Tags: ns2

// some functions need modification:

Modifications in aodv.cc

void AODV::rt_resolve(Packet *p)

This function is invoked in two situations. First, when a mobile node is to send a
data packet and second, when an intermediate mobile node receives a data packet
which it must forward toward its destination.
If the function is invoked by a (source) mobile node that wants to send data
packets to some destination node, there is a check to determine if the destination
is a fixed node and the route to the fixed node is invalid. If this is the case,
the (source) mobile node broadcasts a RREQ_I message to discover a gateway.
Otherwise, the mobile node acts as described in the AODV draft without any
modifications.
If the function is invoked by an intermediate node which has received a data
packet which must be forwarded, the packet is processed differently depending
on if the intermediate node is a mobile node or a gateway. If the intermediate
node is a mobile node and it has a default route, the data packet is destined for a
fixed node. Therefore, the intermediate mobile node updates its route entry for
the fixed node and forwards the packet toward the gateway. On the other hand,
if the intermediate node is a gateway, it has received a data packet from a fixed
node destined for a mobile node. Consequently, the gateway broadcasts a RREQ
message to discover a route to the destination.

void AODV::sendRequest(nsaddr_t dst, u_int8_t flag)

This function is invoked when a mobile node needs to find a route to a destination
node by broadcasting a RREQ. The RREQ is broadcasted according to the
expanding ring search algorithm described in Section 3.3.1. However, when a
RREQ has been broadcasted through the whole network, i.e. when a mobile node
has done a network-wide search without receiving any corresponding RREP, it
assumes that the destination node is a fixed node located on the Internet. First,
the mobile node updates its route entry for the fixed node. Then, it checks for
buffered packets destined for the fixed node. In case there are such packets, they
are forwarded toward the gateway.
This function is also invoked when a mobile node needs to find a route to a
gateway by broadcasting a RREQ_I. The RREQ_I is broadcasted in the same
way as a RREQ message. A mobile node needs to find a route to a gateway
when it detects a link break and the destination of the route is a fixed node.

void AODV::recvRequest(Packet *p)

This function is invoked when a mobile node receives a RREQ or a RREQ_I
message. The message is processed differently depending on if the node is a
mobile node or a gateway. If the node is a mobile node, the code runs without
any modifications, i.e. the node tries to unicast back a RREP to the originator of
the RREQ message. However, in case the node is a gateway, a RREP_I is unicast
back to the originator of the RREQ message.

void AODV::sendReply(nsaddr_t ipdst, u_int32_t hop_count, nsaddr_t rpdst,
u_int32_t rpseq, u_int32_t lifetime, double timestamp, u_int8_t flag)

This function is invoked by a node that has received a RREQ or a RREQ_I message
and either it is the destination or has a fresh route to the destination. The
function just unicasts back a RREP or RREP_I message (depending on the value
in the “flag” field) to the originator of the RREQ or RREQ_I. See comments
about function recvRequest.

void AODV::recvReply(Packet *p)

This function is invoked when a mobile node receives a RREP or a RREP_I
message. The message is processed differently depending on if it is a RREP or
a RREP_I. If the message is a RREP, the code runs without any modifications.
However, if the message is a RREP_I the mobile node saves the address of the
gateway and creates a (or updates the) default route with the address of the gateway
as the next hop. If the mobile node already has a route to another gateway
than the originator of the newly received RREP_I message, it performs gateway
selection with the number of hops to the gateways as metric.
Then the mobile node checks if it has any packets queued in its buffer destined
for a fixed node. If such packets exist and there exists a valid default route, all
packets queued in the buffer are forwarded toward the gateway.
If hybrid gateway discovery method is used, RREP_Is are broadcasted by the
gateway periodically. When a mobile node receives any of these RREP_Is it updates
its route entry for the gateway that originated the RREP_I and rebroadcasts
it so other mobile nodes can receive the gateway information. If a gateway receives
a RREP_I, it discards the message and does not rebroadcast it, to reduce
unnecessary network load.

rt_entry* AODV::find_send_entry(rt_entry *rt)

A function that searches the routing table and returns the correct route that a
packet should be sent to, i.e. it finds the correct next hop that the packets should
be forwarded to. This is needed since default routes, which are not valid next
hops, have been introduced. The routing table is searched for a correct next hop
only if the destination is a fixed node, otherwise (if the destination is a mobile
node) the function just return the next hop as indicated in the routing table.
As an example, take a look at Figure 4.3 in Section 4.5.3. If this function is
not invoked, the packets destined for FN will be sent to next hop “DEFAULT”
which is defined as -10 in aodv.h. Since there is no node with this address, the
packets will be dropped. Therefore, this function is invoked to find the correct
next hop, MN_A in this example. Hence, the packets are forwarded to MN_A
which forwards them to the gateway which forwards them toward FN.

i can't modifiy the code because i am beginner please help me 
thanx in advance